# How to use np.where in creating new column using previous rows with formula?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

This is a continuation of my question or somewhat relevant to my initial question "How to use `np.where` in creating new column using previous rows?"

I am converting an excel file to python since excel can no longer run (or it takes a while to run a hundred of thousands of rows). This is the sample table that I want to convert.

[image: Table from Excel]

Wherein I am running this formula to column C

```
=IF(B2="new",A2,C3+1)
```

Column A and B are inputs and Column C is output.

Column C can be derived if B2 is equal to "new" it will result in the value of column A
and if not equal to "new" it will result to the previous value (or next value) +1.

I tried adding 1 to the previous code that was suggested and yields to a different result. This is the code.

```
df['Previous'] = np.where(df['Status']=='new', df['Count'], np.nan)    
df['Previous'] = df['Previous'].bfill().astype(int) +1
```

This snapshot is the result of the code when I ran it.

[image: Result 2]

Thanks a lot.

Special mention to @SeaBean for helping me.

Comment: `np.where` is good for creating the values for a new column based on values in other columns, taking all row values **at once**.  But you are processing the rows sequentially, with one row dependent on the previous.  `where` is not an iterator.  Look at `df['Status']=='new'` by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do it with additional `groupby` key with `cumsum`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(df.Status.eq('new').iloc[::-1].cumsum()).cumcount(ascending=False) + df.Count.where(df.Status.eq('new')).bfill()
df
Out[219]: 
    Count Status  Previous    new
0       4    old         4    4.0
1       3    old         3    3.0
2       2    old         2    2.0
3       1    new         1    1.0
4      40    old        13   13.0
5      30    old        12   12.0
6      20    old        11   11.0
7      10    new        10   10.0
8     400    old       103  103.0
9     300    old       102  102.0
10    200    old       101  101.0
11    100    new       100  100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following codes:

```
df['Previous'] = df['Count'].where(df['Status'] =='new').bfill()
df['Group_ID'] = df['Status'][::-1].eq('new').cumsum()
df['Previous'] = df.groupby('Group_ID', as_index=False)['Previous'].transform(lambda x: (x[::-1] + (x[::-1] == x[::-1].shift()).cumsum()).sort_index()).astype(int)


print(df)

    Count Status  Previous  Group_ID
0       4    old         4         3
1       3    old         3         3
2       2    old         2         3
3       1    new         1         3
4      40    old        13         2
5      30    old        12         2
6      20    old        11         2
7      10    new        10         2
8     400    old       103         1
9     300    old       102         1
10    200    old       101         1
11    100    new       100         1
```

You can further remove the `Group_ID` created to aid the processing by the following:

```
df = df.drop(columns='Group_ID')

print(df)

    Count Status  Previous
0       4    old         4
1       3    old         3
2       2    old         2
3       1    new         1
4      40    old        13
5      30    old        12
6      20    old        11
7      10    new        10
8     400    old       103
9     300    old       102
10    200    old       101
11    100    new       100
```

Comment: As seen from BENY's solution, which has a very similar approach as mine, I can further simplify my 3rd line of codes to:  `df['Previous'] += df.groupby('Group_ID', as_index=False)['Previous'].cumcount(ascending=False)`   Good point!

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by using .loc

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Count': [4, 3, 2, 1, 40, 30, 20, 10, 400, 300, 200, 100],
    'Status': [
        'old', 'old', 'old', 'new', 'old', 'old', 'old', 'new', 'old', 'old',
        'old', 'new'
    ],
    'Previous': [4, 3, 2, 1, 13, 12, 11, 10, 103, 102, 101, 100]
})

df.loc[df['Status'] == 'new', 'Previous'] = df.loc[df['Status'] == 'new',
                                                   'Count']

df.loc[df['Status'] != 'new', 'Previous'] = df['Previous'].shift(-1).add(1)

print(df)
```

The result:

```
    Count Status  Previous
0       4    old       4.0
1       3    old       3.0
2       2    old       2.0
3       1    new       1.0
4      40    old      13.0
5      30    old      12.0
6      20    old      11.0
7      10    new      10.0
8     400    old     103.0
9     300    old     102.0
10    200    old     101.0
11    100    new     100.0
```

Comment: It seems I have a different result.
My 'Previous' result is NaN, NaN, 2.0, 1.0, NaN, NaN, 11.0, 10.0, NaN, NaN, 101.0, 100.0
I don't know what went wrong with my code, but I had a different result.

Comment: The same with your code, just without the 'Previous' column.